# Wordpress: Woocommerce Pdf Template

Tags: php, css, wordpress, pdf, woocommerce

I work on a WordPress based website: [Thamon.co.uk](http://www.Thamon.co.uk). I have 2 questions about custom Woocommerce PDF Templates. I can't code in PHP and don't know where to place the custom files.

1) I want to make a really simple packing slip, which will include just my address and my customer's shipping address on the left side in Google Font Muli 300 21pt. And it should be limited to strictly top left quarter of the A4 document.

2) I am currently not sure if my website is sending any confirmation emails to my customers. How to make sure I am sending the customer's PDF Invoice to them? How to adjust the text in the email to be: "Thank you for your purchase. Your order number is #Number-Of-Invoice. Please find attached your payment invoice".

Comment: You need to employ someone who knows all the technologies you dont. This is not the place for that. [Please read, What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: That is a very useful advice, thank you for stopping by and investing 2 minutes of your time to reply :) Have a great day.